# Regex max length, ignore specific word combination

Tags: javascript, regex, ember.js

I've made this regex to check the max length of a string:

```
/^[\[\]\/\w\s.,:;!?€¥£¢$-]{0,250}$/
```

The user needs to add 
[link] link text [/link] to the string to add a link. In my regex I want to ignore these [link][/link] for the max length of 250 characters.

How should I do this?

Comment: Could you `.replace()` the [link][/link] from the string for the length check?

Comment: Hmm yeah that would be an idea. Than I should replace it before the check and place the [link] [/link] back after the check eg when the user is saving the string.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking

Comment: Mehh that isn't working either. I use [Ember Validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations) and Ember Validations observes the string instantly so when I replace the [link][/link] it will be replaced also in the template.

Comment: @AlvinVogelzang Post the code you are using. Nobody can really tell where you are wrong when we don't see your code.